# Particle system not linking particles at the object origin

Tags: modifiers, particles, scale

I'm attempting to make a cherry tree in blender, but the particle system displays all of the cherry blossoms inside the branch despite their object origin being on the very tip of the stem. How do I get the particle system to start rendering it from the stem instead of the middle of the flower?
[image: TreeBranch]

Comment: It sounds like you're doing it correctly. Could you post your blend file?

Comment: Sure! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SJNyxfsKA-wbMGBmGN37Am9u1w_MdbDe/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it looks like the main problem is actually pretty simple. The particle system is set to render from the collection `FlowerBunch1`, but it looks like `Bunch1` is the collection you've been working on. So changing that fixed the worst of the problem. (You can also check [Pick Random](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/render.html#collection) so it randomly selects a blossom in the collection instead of cycling sequentially)

[image: Changing particle collection]

> As an aside, the collections listed with an `F` (including `FlowerBunch1`) have a [fake user](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/data_blocks.html#protected) (see also: [term in 2.79 manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/data_system/data_blocks.html#fake-user)) keeping them in the blend file, even though they aren't in the scene anymore. If you want to remove these entirely (and you're sure they aren't needed or referenced elsewhere), you can switch the outliner to show the blend file, then right click the collection to delete it from the file.
>
> [image: Removing a protected data-block]
>
> Or alternatively the fake user can be set/removed in the `ID Data` sub-menu and the collection added back in with `Link to Scene`.

At this point the blossoms should be mostly connected correctly. Just make sure to check that all the objects in the collection have their origin where you want it to connect to the branch. The bent blossom `Circle.006` is a touch off, and the large bunch object `Circle.004` is a little disconnected. It may need to be modified to have the stems come together closer to its origin, so they all appear connected to the branch.

[image: Object origins]

---

And this goes a bit beyond the scope of your question, but the rotation of the blossoms is also making it hard to tell sometimes where it's connecting. Here's a couple suggestions as a starting point, but do whatever will get the results you're looking for:

- Rotating the blossoms to be aligned with the X axis allows the particle system to know which way the blossom is facing
  [image: Setting rotation of blossoms]
- Orienting the particles to the branch's [normal](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html#normals) so it points outward. Using a bit less random rotation, but with more random phase (spin).
  [image: Tweaking particle rotation settings]

Note: To keep it simple, I removed the bunch (and the empty) from the collection `Bunch1` for these examples, so that only the single blossoms would be added to the tree.

Comment: Perfect! That makes a ton more sense. Thanks much